# HTML Form - Responses not being sent via email in proper order

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML form using tables but the responses being submitted via email are not in the order they appear on the form.

This is the current order of the email output being sent:

Products Interested In?: 
DOB: 
Phone Number: 
Insurance ID: 
City: 
Name: 
State: 
Address2: 
Address1: 
HMO or PPO: 
Zip: 
Email Address: 
Insurance Name:

If somebody could provide guidance it would be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<form name="form1">


<br><br>

<table border="2px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-color: Black; border-bottom:1px solid black;">

<tr>
<td><b>Your Full Name: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="60" style="width:300px;" required /></td>
 </tr>

<tr> 
<td><b>Your Email Address: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email Address" maxlength="60" style="width:300px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Your Phone Number: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Phone Number" maxlength="15" style="width:150px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Your Date of Birth (MMDDYY): </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="DOB" maxlength="6" style="width:80px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Your Insurance Name: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Insurance Name" maxlength="60" style="width:300px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Your Insurance Type (PPO, HMO): </b></td>
<td><select id="HMO_PPO" name="HMO or PPO"><option value="">Please select one</option><option value="PPO">PPO</option><option value="HMO">HMO</option></select>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Your Insurance ID: </b></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="Insurance ID" maxlength="25" style="width:150px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mailing Address: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Address1" maxlength="60" style="width:300px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Mailing Address 2: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Address2" maxlength="60" style="width:300px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>City: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="City" maxlength="20" style="width:180px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>State: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="State" maxlength="15" style="width:120px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Zip Code: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Zip" maxlength="5" style="width:80px;" required /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Products Interested In? </b></td>
 <td><textarea name="Products Interested In?" rows="3" cols="40" style="width:300px;"></textarea></td>
</tr>


</div>
</table> <br />
</div>
</table> <br />

<br><br>
<tr>
<td><b>Medical Notes: </b></td>
<td><input name="file1" type="file" /> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><b>Doctors RX: </b></td>
<td><input name="file2" type="file" /></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.100forms.com/js/FORMKEY:LUEBN4Q6D2XN"></script> 
<br><br>
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

<br><br>
</td></tr>
 </table><br />
 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The order of the form elements in the table/DOM does not in any way affect the order that they are put into the actual email output. The server-side script that you're pointing to (in this case, 100forms.com's script) determines that order. That order could be figured out via the actual `POST`/`GET` arrays, or some ordering script by 100forms. You should check and see if you can modify that order on their site.

Comment: As a secondary note, if you have access to a server that's hosting the HTML you posted, and that server can run PHP, you can write your own mailing script using the PHP `mail()` function, assuming you either 1) do not have access to 100forms's output order, or 2) want to have more control over the email output.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if 100forms can help me.  And you nailed it on the head, I cannot run PHP through Volusion's ecommerce platform.